# I cannot see a way to take an element from std::queue

Tags: c++, stl, queue

Excuse me, if I'm repeating a question, but I do not find the same.
What are right actions to extract an element from the standard queue?

```
T Pop ()
{ T rout;

  EnterCriticalSection (pCSection);
  rout = Queue.front (); // here the link is returned
  Queue.pop ();          // here destructor is called
  LeaveCriticalSection (pCSection);

  return rout; // -->> there everything falls
}
```

I have a class `T` with dynamic memory management and copy constructor, in the line with `front()` the copy constructor is not called automatically.
Destructor frees the memory at the end of the scope, and I have the entity with garbage.

How can I force the copy constr?

Comment: Does `T` provide a proper copy constructor for your actual case? _"Maybe force the copy constructor?"_ sounds like a pretty good idea. Also _"there everything falls"_ isn't a very good description of your actual problems.

Comment: You should check the queues size, before calling `Queue.front();` BTW.

Comment: The entire code is useless if T is a pointer.

Comment: "Everything falls" is a joke. I have a class T with dynamic memory and copy constructor, in the line with front() the constructor of coping is not called automatically. Destructor frees the memory, and I have the entity with garbage. How can I force the copy constr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem that you don't have a copy assignment operator? You mention the copy constructor, but you're not copy constructing anything in your code. Perhaps you meant to do:

```
T Pop ()
{ 
    assert(!Queue.empty());

    EnterCriticalSection (pCSection);
    T rout = Queue.front ();
    Queue.pop ();
    LeaveCriticalSection (pCSection);

    return rout;
}
```

Or even:

```
    T rout(std::move(Queue.front()));
```

Comment: I'm interesting in pattern of extracting elements from std::queue, because this class returns the links only. Thank you, now I understand - there are two ways 1. redefine the operator=, 2. force the copy constructor. Wonderful!

Comment: I'm afraid a _real world solution_ would get a bit more complicated: 1. The `assert()` doesn't really help much in reality (unless checked beforé calling `Pop()`). 2. The check for `!Queue.empty()` should be done inside the _critical section_ 3. If the check is done inside the function, one has to decide, if` `T()` should be returned as a dummy value, or an exception should be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I have a class T with dynamic memory and copy constructor, ... **How can I force the copy constr?**"*

That's easy

```
T rout(Queue.front());
```

Most probably you've been missing to provide a proper assignment operator for `T` along. See also here please [**What is the Rule of Three?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

---

Also as you're mentioning *dynamic memory management* done in your class `T`. Ease up yourself please, and use [standard container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), or even standard [dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) features of c++ preferably to use `new` and `delete` directly.

Comment: Thank you, everything is clear.

Comment: @so-olitary Fine. I gave some additional advice.